# simpler recursive code runs slower than iterative version of the same thing

Tags: python, recursion, time

I wrote this python code to give the Harmonic Series of a certain value n both recursively and iteratively. Here is the functions:

```
def H(n):
    if (n <= 0): raise ValueError("n must be bigger than 0.")
    if (n == 1): return 1
    else: return sum([1/x for x in range(1,n+1)])

def H_rec(n):
    if (n <= 0): raise ValueError("n must be bigger than 0.")
    if (n == 1): return 1
    else: return 1/n + H(n-1)
```

Then, when I run the code 10 times for each, I get the following times:

```
RECURSIVE TIMES [22.755768060684204, 17.231882095336914, 14.965636014938354, 14.277509927749634, 14.0553719997406, 13.788002014160156, 13.338942766189575, 13.72638201713562, 14.690818071365356, 14.236813068389893] 
RECURSIVE MEAN: 15.30671260356903
ITERATIVE TIMES [15.093524932861328, 12.801156759262085, 13.350629091262817, 13.806081056594849, 13.29387378692627, 13.876484870910645, 12.934008121490479, 13.859009981155396, 13.350301027297974, 13.590226888656616] 
ITERATIVE MEAN: 13.595529651641845
```

The code is supposed to find `H_rec(100000000)` and `H(100000000)`, which are fairly big numbers.

I don't understand exactly why the recursive definition takes longer when the way it's defined seems to require less computation. The iterative one requires forming a list and finding its sum, while the recursive one just sums `1/n + H(n-1)`.

What is so misleading about this recursion? Why is it slow?

Comment: I would say you have 100000000 * 2 additional tests in the recursive code but I am not sure of the changes in computation times

Comment: Function calls (calls to user-defined functions, to be precise) are relatively expensive in Python; the recursive version simply has more overhead.

Comment: @chepner Why is that exactly?

Comment: It's worth pointing that list comprehension is a lot faster than function calls, so that's probably a main reason for the speed difference.

Comment: They are both doing the same thing: looping through a list of numbers and summing their inverses.  The list comprehension version iterates through the range, creates the list, and sums all values. And it does this after only 2 if comparisons.  That is probably the most efficient way to implement the algorithm in Python.  The recursive version performs a function call, 2 comparisons and a return for every element being summed.  A lot of overhead.  Try to rejigger the recursive version to remove the extra comparisons and see what happens.

Comment: @AlanLeuthard Those extra comparisons are necessary; without them, you have infinite recursion. The non-recursive function ultimately makes similar comparisons (in the internal loop of the `sum` function), but they happen inside the interpreter, rather than being separate Python instructions.

Comment: Its not simple recursive. It recurses with a continuation where the result needs to be added to something in the current  frame. It could be made simple recursive by using an accumulator. Python doesn't favor recursion though so running your code (after the fix) with a large number just blows the stack so it really doesn't matter since it doesn't even work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code executed inside the Python interpreter is fastest. Python code (which is compiled to Python byte code that is interpreted by a virtual machine) is slower. User-defined function calls are slowest of all, because the virtual machine has to manage its own call stack to track the execution environments.

Consider the following code:

```
def S1(n):
    return sum(range(1,n))

def S2(n):
    rv = 0
    for i in range(1,n):
        rv += i
    return rv

def S3(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return n + S3(n-1)
```

`S1` is the fastest; as much work as possible is pushed into the interpreter. `S2` is slower because now each addition is a separate Python instruction to be interpreted. `S3` is slowest because now each addition involves *another* function call to get its second operand; as noted before, function calls are slow in Python.

```
>>> print(timeit.timeit('S1(50)', globals=globals()))
1.2118524569996225
>>> print(timeit.timeit('S2(50)', globals=globals()))
3.262354401002085
>>> print(timeit.timeit('S3(50)', globals=globals()))
10.102635376999388
```

Answer (score 4):

Your recursive function is calling the iterative one in `else: return 1/n + H(n-1)`, you need to modify it as the following:

```
def H_rec(n):
    if (n <= 0): raise ValueError("n must be bigger than 0.")
    if (n == 1): return 1
    else: return 1/n + H_rec(n-1) #Fix this line
```

Comment: That bug only explains why the recursive function is as close to the iterative one in running time as it is. Fixing the bug only *increases* the running time of the recursive version.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit weird but shouldn't the recursive still run faster (assuming what I assumed before, namely that the recursion requires less operations overall based on seeing the code itself) because 1 instance has run recursively while the rest ran iteratively?

Comment: @RobertVunabandi The recursive version doesn't require fewer operations; it still performs `n` divisions and adds `n` numbers, but it does so at the Python level (with additional function overhead) instead of inside the Python interpreter itself.

Comment: This answer is just *wrong*; fixing the bug to make the recursive function fully recursive actually makes it *slower*.

Comment: I guess the answer doesn't answer why it's slower, but it's still worth pointing out that the code wasn't fully recursive. I ran it again, and the recursive version actually takes much longer.